# Multiple stdin.write usage with python

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, python-2.5

I have an Visual studio application which takes interactive arguments like

```
- PATH
```

On input , MENU #1 is displayed (which again accepts arguments/user input) and again on input , MENU #2 is displayed.

I need to call this VS application (exe) from Python . I have limitation to stick to Python 2.5 version.

I tried using subprocess.popen and stdin.write.

I am able to parse through MENU#1 but unable to proceed further to MENU #2 and so on...

Any hints/examples on achieving the above.?

My code looks like:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('app.exe',stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=None)
p.stdin.write(file_path)  # for menu 1

time.sleep(0.5)

p.stdin.write('0')         # for menu 2..

...

o,e = p.communicate()
```

Comment: Are you sure that the exe reads from stdin and not directly from console?

Comment: Not very sure. Janne. I pressume that the exe reads from stdin (becoz, if in case i remove p.stdin.write('0') the behavior observed is as expected.)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`pexpect` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect) instead; it'll let you control a program with interactive input much better than the subprocess module can.

```
import pexpect

p = pexpect.spawn('app.exe')
p.sendline(file_path)
p.expect('Menu #2:.*')
p.sendline('0')
```

For windows, you can use [`wexpect.py`](http://sage.math.washington.edu/home/goreckc/sage/wexpect/) instead, a port of the `pexpect` module to the Windows console.

Comment: Dear Martijn, Many thanks for the advice. But i pressume that the pexpect module is for Linux environment. Currently i have setup running in Windows 7 / XP environment.

Comment: Have you tried it? It's a pure-python module, so there won't be any compilation issues.

Comment: Dear Martijn, Yes i tried it.>>> import pexpect
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\pexpect.py", line 85, in <module>
    support it. Pexpect is intended for UNIX-like operating systems.""")
ImportError: No module named resource

A critical module was not found. Probably this operating system does not
support it. Pexpect is intended for UNIX-like operating systems.
>>>

Comment: Ah, the documentation states it'll work in a Cygwin environment, not on just Windows. Sorry about that.